# Purpose of function is unknown, what does it do?

Tags: c++, c, function, math, complex-numbers

Could someone please help me understand what this function is doing if the input is a complex number `a+bi` and `real = a, imag = b`

I have no idea what it could be computing but maybe I am missing something obvious?

```
double function(double real, double imag)
{
  double y;
  double a;
  double b;
  a = fabs(real);
  b = fabs(imag);
  if (a < b) 
  {
    a /= b;
    y = b * sqrt(a * a + 1.0);
  } 
  else if (a > b) 
  {
    b /= a;
    y = a * sqrt(b * b + 1.0);
  } 
  else if (b == NAN) 
  {
    y = b;
  } 
  else 
  {
    y = a * sqrt(2);
  }

  return y;
}
```

Comment: It's just `abs()`, the absolute value. `sqrt(real^2 + imag^2)`. Not clear why it's obfuscated this way.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: It is not obfuscated. It is avoiding overflows.

Comment: It seems odd that the route to produce the result of the function is different depending on whether `real` or `imag` is NAN (though the `y = a * sqrt(2);` does produce a NAN if `a` is a NAN).  There's also an `isnan()` function in `<math.h>`. It would be better to use that than the `b == NAN` test because there are many varieties of NAN with mulitple representations.

Comment: Computing the magnitude of the complex value `(real, imag)` and jumping through some simple hoops to avoid overflows.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler They are different because the last branch does not only cover `a == NAN`  but also `a==b`. So theast two branches are aquivalent to `if(b== NAN) {return NAN;} else if(a == NAN) {return NAN;} else { return sqrt(2)*a; /* only is reached for a==b*/}` and the last two branches of this representation are just made to one.

Comment: @Peter — up to a point.  As I noted, there are multiple bit patterns for NaN; the value used in `b == NAN` can only be a single pattern.  Therefore, that test may be able detect one bit pattern, but it cannot reliably detect them all, especially since, as you mention, even bit-wise identical NaN values do not compare equal.  My original comment used NAN for both `NAN` and NaN, which was conscious but lazy.  I'd be curious to see a citation for the `NAN` behaviour you describe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Looks can be deceiving. The third case is never executed. `b == NAN` is always false, even if the operands have the same bit pattern. Despite the author’s attempt, the code does not handle NaN inputs differently depending on which operand is a NaN, or if both are. They all fall through to the fourth case, which gets a wrong answer when `b` is a NaN and `a` is not.

Comment: @Peter: Concluding that this code is using a redefined or non-standard `NAN` requires assuming the code is right and author has gone to some trouble to circumvent the C standard to that end while apparently using the standard `fabs` declared in `<math.h>`. A more likely assumption is that the code is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is a defective attempt to compute the magnitude (absolute value) of the complex number passed to it without incurring needless overflow.

Consider the complex number *a* + *b* i, where *a* and *b* are the values assigned to `a` and `b` in the first few lines of the function. Its magnitude is √(*a*<sup>2</sup>+*b*<sup>2</sup>). However, if *a* or *b* is large, the floating-point calculation `a*a` might overflow the finite range of the floating-point format and produce infinity (∞) even though the magnitude is within the range. As a simple example, let *a* be 2<sup>1000</sup> and *b* be 0. Then the magnitude is √(2<sup>2000</sup>+0) = 2<sup>1000</sup>, but computing `sqrt(a*a + b*b)` yields infinity. (Since `a*a` overflowed and produced ∞, and the rest of the calculations then produce ∞ too.)

The code attempts to solve that by dividing the smaller of *a* and *b* by the larger and using a calculation that is mathematically equivalent but that does not overflow. For example, if `a < b` is true, it executes:

```
a /= b;
y = b * sqrt(a * a + 1.0);
```

Then `a /= b` produces a value less than 1, so all calculation prior to the last are safely within the floating-point finite range: `a * a` is less than 1, `a * a + 1.0` is less than 2, and `sqrt(a * a + 1.0)` is less than 1.42. When we multiply by `b`, the final result might overflow to ∞. There are two reasons this might happen: The magnitude of *a* + *b* i might exceed the floating-point finite range, so the overflow is correct. Or rounding in the prior calculations might have caused `sqrt(a * a + 1.0)` to be slightly larger than the mathematical result and sufficient to cause `b * sqrt(a * a + 1.0)` to overflow when actual value of the magnitude is within the range. As this is not our focus, I will not analyze this case further in this answer.

Aside from that rounding issue, the first two cases are fine. However, this code is incorrect:

```
else if (b == NAN)
```

Per IEEE-754 2008 5.11 and IEEE-754 1985 5.7, a NaN is not less than, equal to, or greater than any operand, including itself. It is *unordered*. This means `b == NAN` must return false if IEEE-754 is used. C 2018 does not require IEEE-754 be used, but footnote 22 (at 5.2.4.2.2 4) says that, if IEC 60559:1989 (effectively IEEE-754) is not supported, the terms “quiet NaN” and “signaling NaN” in the C standard are intended to apply to encodings with similar behavior. And 7.12 5 tells us that `NAN` expands to a `float` representing a quiet NaN. Thus, in `b == NAN`, `NAN` should behave as an IEEE-754 NaN, and so `b == NAN` should yield 0, for false.

Therefore, this code governed by `else if (b == NAN)` is never executed:

```
y = b;
```

Instead, execution falls through to the `else`, which executes:

```
y = a * sqrt(2);
```

If `a` is a NaN, the result is a NaN, as desired. However, if `a` is a number and `b` is a NaN, this produces a number as a result when the desired result would be a NaN. Thus, the code is broken.